# AspNet Role provider kicking in and it shouldn't be

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting this error:

```
Line 246:       <roleManager>
Line 247:           <providers>
Line 248:               <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"     connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/"  type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 249:               <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 250:           </providers>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 248
```

However, it shouldn't be as we're not using the aspnetroleprovider.  But it's in the machine.config.  Other sites don't have this problem.  What could be making it pick up the aspnetsqlroleprovider?

Answer (score 6):

**fix**

add `enableSimpleMembership` with value `false` app setting to your `web.config`.

**cause**

```
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

will cause `Roles.Enabled` flag to be set to `false`, as expected,

**but** there is 'WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity' that says:

```
internal static void PreAppStartInit()
{
  if (!ConfigUtil.SimpleMembershipEnabled)
    return;
  ...
  Roles.Enabled = true;
  const string BuiltInRolesProviderName = "AspNetSqlRoleProvider";
  var builtInRoles = Roles.Providers[BuiltInRolesProviderName];
  if (builtInRoles != null)
  {
      var simpleRoles = CreateDefaultSimpleRoleProvider(BuiltInRolesProviderName, currentDefault: builtInRoles);
      Roles.Providers.Remove(BuiltInRolesProviderName);
      Roles.Providers.Add(simpleRoles);
  }
  ...
}
```

this will override roleManager setting (this code is executed before RoleManager module is), including adding AspNetSqlRoleProvider

to disable 'SimpleMembership' you can add app setting `enableSimpleMembership` with `value="false"` (web.config):

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

this will prevent webmatrix from reconfiguring `RoleManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `<clear/>` to your web.config's section of role providers. On this way you avoid inheriting if you don't use one. You should add it also for `Membership` and `Profile` providers section.

```
<roleManager>
   <providers>
      <clear/>
   </providers>
   ....
```

Edit: Maybe you need to remove it explicitely:

```
<roleManager>
       <providers>
          <clear/>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" />
```

Another try:

Disable the role provider:

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="false" />
</system.web>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx#paght000013_step2

Comment: Yeah, tried that sorry - clearing all role providers makes it whinge about there not being a default role provider, or the default role provider not being available

Comment: @Paul: Edited, try to remove it.

Comment: No I mean you can't remove it at all: Parser Error Message: Default Role Provider could not be found.

Comment: @Paul: and the next try, disable the default role provider(see my edit).

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, then i'm afraid that i'm  running out of ideas.