# How do I not use the App_Data folder in an ASP MVC4 application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Everything works fine locally, but when I publish, I get the error below. I am using forms authentication, but I define my own connection string to a non-sqlexpress database. I don't understand why my application would need access to create a database (or anything else) in the App_Data folder, because my database is not/will not be there. Any help is appreciated.

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog={my db};Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Error:

Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory

Description: For security reasons, the identity 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' (under which this web application is running), does not have permissions to create the App_Data subdirectory within the application root directory. ASP.NET stores the Microsoft SQL Express Database file used for services such as Membership and Profile in the App_Data subdirectory of your application.

Edit: It tells me how to fix the error by adding the App_Data folder and providing the correct permissions, but I don't understand why I need this folder at all, and if I can avoid changing permissions, I'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally figured out how to stop ASP from trying to create the ASPNETDB.MDF database in the App_Data folder automatically. What I found worked combined two existing stackoverflow answers:

[Disable SQL Membership Provider (ASP.Net Forms Authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481132/disable-sql-membership-provider-asp-net-forms-authentication)

It turns out that, on the production machine, the SQL membership provider was defined in machine.config. I don't think the ops team changed anything from the default Windows 2008 install, so that's probably generally the case for that platform.

To remove references to any SQL providers defined at a higher level include the following in your web.config

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile>
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</profile>
```

[AspNet Role provider kicking in and it shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116736/aspnet-role-provider-kicking-in-and-it-shouldnt-be)

To disable 'SimpleMembership' you can add app setting enableSimpleMembership with value="false" (web.config). This will prevent webmatrix from reconfiguring RoleManager.

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the 'connectionStringName' property of the 'membership' node in your web.config is set to your connectionstring, like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         connectionStringName="DataContext"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Stephen. I think I included a nuget package or something that referenced or automatically included the DefaultMembershipProvider even though I didn't use it in my project. Ideally, I was trying to get rid of it altogether so that I didn't need the App_Data folder to store any files/localdb.

Comment: If you don't use it, you can remove it from the web.config

Comment: That's just it, it wasn't referenced in my web.config. Apparently it is in the machine.config file (I wasn't familiar with this), and I didn't want to change anything that could impact other applications/future development.

Comment: I see. Nice you found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
*<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile>
    <providers>
        <clear />       
    </providers>
</profile>*
```