# How to disable AspNetSqlMembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4

I need to disable AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in my project.

in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

</connectionStrings>

<membership>
<providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                     applicationName="/" />
</providers>
</membership>
```

I need membership disable at all. Now membership try to connect to DB. I do not need that.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481132/disable-sql-membership-provider-asp-net-forms-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Remove it out of your `web.config`

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 applicationName="/" />
```

Comment: I try that. System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: need by default.

Comment: @DarienFawkes: Try to remove all <providers>?